# Foreach loop of 2 descendant models in razor view MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Let's suppose I have 3 models:

```
Account;
Expense;
Profit;
```

The **Expense** and **Profit** models are linked to **Account** with FK Acoount_Id.

Now I want to have a view where I show an HTML table for each account with their own movements (lines inside Profit and Expense datatables). I want them to be ordered by the inserted Date, which is a field of Profit and Expense tables.

How do I implement that Foreach inside the view?

Something like this logic:

```
Foreach (var item in ( (AccountModel.Profit join AccountModel.Expense).orderedByDate Desc) {
... Do stuff...
}
```

**Account Model:**

```
namespace dBudget.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Account
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Account()
        {
            this.Expenses = new HashSet<Expense>();
            this.Profits = new HashSet<Profit>();
            this.UserAccounts = new HashSet<UserAccount>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Profit> Profits { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Expense Model:**

```
namespace dBudget.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Expense
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Loan_Id { get; set; }
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
        public int Account_Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Loan Loan { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Profit Model:**

```
namespace dBudget.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Profit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Loan_Id { get; set; }
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
        public int Account_Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Loan Loan { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any effort from yourself so far?

Comment: @bit , I search the web, but i'm new to MVC and I'm not english native, so it's not that easy to find... I tried some things with the help of intellisense, no luck until now...

Comment: Can you post your model code please? When you say linked, is that just in the database or is it also linked in your class? E.g. `Account` contains a `List<Expense>`

Comment: @bit, maybe i should build a viewmodel with this, returning only the accounts for the logged in user. But this is not a topic that I know about. How do I build a viewmodel to this? I didn't build any viewmodel yet.

Comment: @Draken, just added the code.

Comment: So you want all the expenses and profits associated with a given account to be displayed?

Comment: Why do you want to keep such complex operations in views,won't it be lot clean and optimized if you do it in any lower layer and only pass the data to be displayed in the view??

Comment: @bit That should do it, i can do the rest. But the goal is to have a view showing all accounts associated with the logged in user (I have a table called 'User' and a table called 'UserAccount' where i link the two tables, I have the models to all those tables too), and for each account I want to show all profits and expenses (single table ordered by date, which is a column of expense and profit tables). I want to show the balance of each account too.

Comment: Yes it will @SamGhatak, but as I said, i'm new to MVC, trying to learn. At this moment I'm trying to build a modelview called 'AccountMovements' to do this, but no success until now... I'll continue trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to your Models folder, name it Movement.cs.
This class will contain the structure of the Movement, which will include all the profit and expense tables.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace dBudget.Models {

    public class Movement {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Account {
        public double Balance { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Movement> Movements { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add a new action to the AccountController.cs file:

```
// GET: Account Movements
public ActionResult Movements(int? id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
    if (account == null) {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    //-- BEGIN SAMPLE DATA - DELETE WHEN YOU HAVE DATABASE FILLED
    var accounts = new List<Account> {
        new Account {Id = 1, Name = "Account 1"}
    };

    account = accounts.First();

    var profits = new List<Profit> {
        new Profit {Id = 1, Account_Id = 1, Value = 20, Description = "Profit 1", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60)},
        new Profit {Id = 2, Account_Id = 1, Value = 30, Description = "Profit 2", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120)},
        new Profit {Id = 3, Account_Id = 1, Value = 60, Description = "Profit 3", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-180)},
    };
    account.Profits = profits;

    var expenses = new List<Expense> {
        new Expense {Id = 1, Account_Id = 1, Value = 10, Description = "Expense 1", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30)},
        new Expense {Id = 2, Account_Id = 1, Value = 40, Description = "Expense 2", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-90)},
        new Expense {Id = 3, Account_Id = 1, Value = 200, Description = "Expense 3", Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-150)},
    };
    account.Expenses = expenses;
    //-- END SAMPLE DATA

    //-- BEGIN Fill Movements
    var movements = new List<Movement> { };

    foreach (Profit p in account.Profits) {

        var m = new Movement { Id = p.Id, Value = p.Value, Description = p.Description, Type = "Profit", Date = p.Date };
        movements.Add(m);

        //-- Add Profits sum to Balance
        account.Balance += p.Value;
    }

    foreach (Expense e in account.Expenses) {

        var m = new Movement { Id = e.Id, Value = e.Value, Description = e.Description, Type = "Expense", Date = e.Date };
        movements.Add(m);

        //-- Add Expenses sum to Balance
        account.Balance -= e.Value;
    }

    account.Movements = movements.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();

    //-- END Fill Movements

    ViewBag.AccountName = account.Name;
    ViewBag.AccountBalance = account.Balance;
    return View(account.Movements);
}
```

Add a new View to the Views/Account folder, name it Movements.cshtml, add this code: (Did some cool things with the Value, green when profit and red when expense, remove if you don't want them)

```
@model IEnumerable<dBudget.Models.Movement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ViewBag.AccountName + " : Movements";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:right;"></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            @if (item.Type.Equals("Profit")) {
                <td style="color:green; text-align:right;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                </td>
            } else {
                <td style="color:red; text-align:right;">
                    - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                </td>
            }
            <td style="text-align:right;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p><strong>Balance: @ViewBag.AccountBalance </strong></p>
```

Then access yoursite/Accounts/Movements/1
It has to be '1' because it's the only account inserted in the demo part, remember? It's in the controller. Don't forget to add some values to the database and clean the demo part after.

Answer (score 2):

From  the comments, you want all the expenses & profits associated with the accounts in one place (Model/ViewModel).

Assuming that your existing classes are :

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // or account number

    // your rest of the properties
    public decimal AmountBalance { get; set; }

}


public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Profit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; } // Foreign key
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

We add a class for the Model like :

```
// Your view model
public class AccountModel
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public List<Profit> Profits { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

Now some dummy data to populate the existing classes:

```
var accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account {Id = 1, AmountBalance = 110},
        new Account {Id = 2, AmountBalance = 120},
    };

var expenses = new List<Expense>
    {
        new Expense {Id = 1, AccountId = 1, Amount = 10},
        new Expense {Id = 2, AccountId = 1, Amount = 40},
        new Expense {Id = 3, AccountId = 2, Amount = 50},
    };

var profits = new List<Profit>
    {
        new Profit {Id = 1, AccountId = 1, Amount = 20},
        new Profit {Id = 2, AccountId = 2, Amount = 30},
        new Profit {Id = 3, AccountId = 2, Amount = 60},
    };
```

Then we form groups of the `Profits` and `Expenses` by the `account number / Id`

```
// Form groups of expenses by the account number / id. Each group will have all the expenses belonging to the same account number / id
var expenseGroupsByAccount = expenses.GroupBy(expense => expense.AccountId).ToList();

// Form groups of profits by the account number / id. Each group will have all the profits belonging to the same account number / id
var profitGroupsByAccount = profits.GroupBy(profit => profit.AccountId).ToList();
```

Finally, we populate the `Model`

```
// Now we can populate the AccountModel, which is essentially an account and all expenses & profits associated with it. 
var accountModels = new List<AccountModel>();
foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    var accountModel = new AccountModel
        {
            Account = account,
            Profits =
                profitGroupsByAccount.Where(profitsGroup => profitsGroup.Key == account.Id)
                                     .SelectMany(g => g)
                                     .ToList(),
            Expenses = expenseGroupsByAccount.Where(expenseGroup => expenseGroup.Key == account.Id)
                                             .SelectMany(g => g)
                                             .ToList()
        };
    accountModels.Add(accountModel);
}
```

Comment: the 3 last blocks should be inside the model or inside a controller?